# Why micro precision/recall is better suited for class imbalance?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, precision-recall

I have three classes. Suppose the number of elements of the first class is 30, the second-30, the third-1000. 
Some algorithm gave predictions and the following error matrix was obtained(rows are predictions, columns are true labels).

```
[[  1   0  10]
 [ 29   2  10]
 [  0  28 980]]
```

From this matrix, it can be seen that the third class is well classified, although other classes are almost always wrong.

The result is the following precision and recall:

```
Precision. 
 micro: 0.927 
 macro: 0.371
Recall. 
 micro: 0.927 
 macro: 0.360
```

From the official documentation and from many articles, questions (for example, from [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/micro-average-vs-macro-average-performance-in-a-multiclass-classification-settin/16001)) it is said that it is better to use micro when classes are unbalanced. Although intuitively it seems that in this case micro shows too good metric values, despite the fact that the two classes are practically not classified.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The micro-precision/recall are not "better" for imbalanced classes.

In fact, if you look at the results, it is clear that the macro precision/recall have very small values when you have bad predictions on an unbalanced dataset (poor results on the less well represented label).

The micro-precision however does take into account the number of elements per class when it is computed.

From sklearn's micro and macro `f1-score` for example (same for precision and recall):

```
'micro':
Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true positives, false negatives and false positives.

'macro':
Calculate metrics for each label, and find their unweighted mean. This does not take label imbalance into account.
```

So macro actually penalises you when you have poor results in a label which is not well represented.

Micro-average on the other hand does not do that as it computes globally the metrics.

For example this means that if you have many samples in class 0, and say, many of the predictions are correct, while few samples in class 1 with many bad predictions, a micro-precision/recall could potentially yield a high number, while a macro-metric (precision/recall/f1-score) would penalise (yield a small number) for poor results on a specific label.

Now it really depends on what you are interested. If you want to globally have good results and you do not care about the distribution of labels, micro-metric could be suitable.

However we usually care about the results on less well-represented classes within our datasets, hence the utility of a macro-metric in spite of the micro-metric.

Comment: It turns out that tips like "micro precision/recall is more preferable for an imbalance" are not quite correct? I just often see such tips.